# Anyone got BizTalk HTTP receive location to work with GET?

Tags: http, get, biztalk

In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561368%28v=BTS.70%29.aspx) for the HTTP Adapter one should get a message with the querystring as body, if you use a receive location address like "/ReceiveApp/btsHTTPReceive.dll?LocationID=1&param1=2".

Using GET on a receive location address like "/ReceiveApp/btsHTTPReceive.dll" will just cause an error.

I have tried "everything" but I cannot get GET to work. The closest I get is to download the actual dll!

In the [configuration documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559072%28v=BTS.70%29.aspx) one is supposed to set allowed Verbs to POST. It sounds to me the problem begins there, but it is the documentation.

Anyone that has been able to use GET and got the querystring as a message?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://kentweare.blogspot.com/2009/06/adventures-with-http-adapter-and-yahoo.html).  It performs a POST instead of a GET.  I suggest using fiddler to view the http specifics.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is two different things. In Kent´s case he wants to request a url with a send port, to get information. In my case I want to expose BizTalk with a receive location accepting HTTP GET. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah not the exact same thing.  I've honestly only used POST before.